# increase by 50 all numbers of lines with "y" coordinate

Tags: algorithm, txt

I need help. The problem: how to change all specific coordinate values by any number. Like multiplying all values of Y coordinates here by 3 or decreasing all X values by 55.

There is notepad file format with many many lines in it. Tbh thats a hideout file from path of exile game. I want to edit some objects there, so i need to manage coordinate values somehow. The reason why i want it - to share with PoE community some hideout files, but i need to move objects in it to make everything looking good.
I am have no clue how to solve it. I hope to find some wise person here <3

Example:

```
 "Arched Gateway": {
      "hash": 3294752266,
      "x": 309,
      "y": 237,
      "r": 1756,
      "fv": 0
    },
    "Arched Gateway": {
      "hash": 3294752266,
      "x": 305,
      "y": 259,
      "r": 4586,
      "fv": 0
    },
    "Arched Gateway": {
      "hash": 3294752266,
      "x": 261,
      "y": 302,
      "r": 11101,
      "fv": 0
    },
```

I want to find out the wat to solve it not manually. Like function in any app or site which can change only Y coordinate values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a JSONata expression to transform your data, see https://try.jsonata.org/.

But first, you need to fix your data as it's not a valid JSON, because of duplicate key 'Arched Gateway'.

If you modify your input like this for example:

```json
{
    "ArchedGateways": [{
            "hash": 3294752266,
            "x": 309,
            "y": 237,
            "r": 1756,
            "fv": 0
        },
        {
            "hash": 3294752266,
            "x": 305,
            "y": 259,
            "r": 4586,
            "fv": 0
        },
        {
            "hash": 3294752266,
            "x": 261,
            "y": 302,
            "r": 11101,
            "fv": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

this JSONata expression would do:

```json
ArchedGateways.{
    'hash': hash,
    'x': x - 55,
    'y': y * 3,
    'r': r,
    'fv': fv
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I very appreciate your help!

But the problem is - i can't modify input because game gives error when importing file with modified data :c
So, i need to keep that duplications of objects. 

I can't write Json script for every object name, sadly
There is from 20 to 100 different object names in each file.

Comment: then I am afraid jsonata won't work for you as it's not able (or at least I am not aware) to work with duplicate keys on input nor output duplicates